# Re-use Patch in Python Test

Tags: python, python-unittest

Not an expert. If I patch a module's method, is it possible to re-use the same patch in other methods of the TestCase?

```
    def load(**kwargs):
      return 1

    def load2(**kwargs):
      return2

    @patch.multiple('module',
                    get_data=MagicMock(side_effect=load),
                    headers=MagicMock(return_value=""))
    def test_get_some_method(self):
      # here is ok

    @patch.multiple('module',
                    get_data=MagicMock(side_effect=load2),
                    headers=MagicMock(return_value=""))
    def test_get_other_method(self):
      # here I get an exception:'load1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given'
```

EDIT
Maybe it is better to use `return_value` instead of side_effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`TestCase.setUpClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) class method for this. The "patcher" returned by `patch` needs to be properly [stopped](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) though, if you don't use it in the form of a decorator or context manager. Thus you should always include that call in `TestCase.tearDownClass`.

Here is a little demo for you.

`code.py`

```py
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, x: float) -> None:
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self) -> float:
        return self._x

    def get_x_times_2(self) -> float:
        return self.get_x() * 2

    def get_x_squared(self) -> float:
        return self.get_x() ** 2

    def print_x(self) -> None:
        print(self.get_x())
```

Say we wanted to test all methods that call `get_x` and with the exact same mock object (for some reason).

---

`test.py`

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code


class SpamTestCase(TestCase):
    get_x_patcher = None
    mock_get_x: MagicMock = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.get_x_patcher = patch.object(code.Spam, "get_x")
        cls.mock_get_x = cls.get_x_patcher.start()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.get_x_patcher.stop()

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.spam = code.Spam(3.14)

    def test_get_x_times_2(self) -> None:
        self.mock_get_x.return_value = 5
        self.assertEqual(10, self.spam.get_x_times_2())

    def test_get_x_squared(self) -> None:
        self.mock_get_x.return_value = 4
        self.assertEqual(16, self.spam.get_x_squared())

    @patch.object(code, "print")
    def test_print_x(self, mock_print: MagicMock) -> None:
        self.mock_get_x.return_value = 10.5
        self.assertIsNone(self.spam.print_x())
        mock_print.assert_called_once_with(10.5)
```

---

However, I don't really see the use case for this. Using regular `setUp` and `tearDown` should be enough to facilitate consistency across all test methods, if you need that and don't want to repeat yourself in multiple decorators/context managers. The mock objects will not be *literally* the same, but created the same way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx. could you elaborate better on the use of the path within setUp?

Comment: @gdm What are you talking about, what "path" in `setUp`? The `setUp` method is just there to always have a `Spam` instance in every test method, so that I don't have to repeat myself. I answered your question whether it is _"possible to re-use the same patch in other methods of the TestCase"_. But based on your own "answer" it seems you want something else entirely. If you want me to amend my answer, you should edit your original post and explain properly what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Daniil'answer, maybe something like this:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
        self.patcher = patch.multiple('lib.MyClass',
                                      get_data=MagicMock(side_effect=load),
                                      headers=MagicMock(return_value="")).start()

        self.my_module = MyClass()

   def test_something(self):
        _ = self.my_module.get_data()
```

Comment: I don't see any connection your original question here. Suddenly here you are opening files. Also you are creating variables and assigning values to attributes (like `.body`, `.mocked_module` and `.aggregated_data`) that you never seem to be using. Your methods here seem to be completely unrelated to those in your original post. This is very confusing...

Comment: yes you're right, sorry. the basic problem is: Mocking some method of a real class which is used in many test methods. In hte excample I re-edited, I mocked the method of MyClass in the setUp. Is it fine?